# App launch browser to view local html file fails

Tags: browser, migration, delphi

We have an old Delphi app running on Windows server, using `RemoteApp` to deliver to users. The app is old, uses Windows VirtualStore due to it writing to program files directory. Works ok on current server but are in need of migrating to new server.

Everything works ok except a report button. It generates the HTML, launches Internet Explorer, but rather than going to the local html file in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\RSRM\temp\report0.html`, the browser goes to default homepage msn.com.

- I've tried UAC on and off with no difference.
- IE enhanced security config is off on both servers.
- I've tried policy local machine zone lockdown security as not configured and enabled
- I've tried UNC path format instead but no luck yet with the browser settings tried, open to suggestions
- None of the original crew are around so I've inherited the maintenance.

**Current server**
- Windows server 2008 R2, SP 1
- IE 9

**New server**
- Windows server 2008 R2, SP 1
- IE 11

Does IE 11 introduce new restrictions?

Since it works on old server, I'm hoping it can on new server with out needing to modify code. Being an old app, the code path may be a challenge (getting the code of someone, and modifying, rather a last resort)

I'm not sure what other settings to try, greatly appreciate ideas.

Cheers Peter

Comment: What happens if you just try `run -> iexplore C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\RSRM\temp\report0.html`?

Comment: From the start menu if I do... `iexplore C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\RSRM\temp\report0.html` it seems to work but if I do `iexplore C:\Program Files (x86)\RSRM\temp\report0.html` it doesn't. Perhaps IE / Windows isn't accessing the VirtualStore properly?